Why in big and medium size firms everything works on a credit system?
I'm following an accounting course.
We are learning about the income statement.
The professor explained that we do not record transactions on a cash-based basis.
Instead, in big and medium sized corporations, everything works on a credit system.
If I buy something from a supplier, I'll pay a few months later.
If I sell something to a customer, I'll get paid a few months later.
Why is it so?
What's wrong with buying from a supplier and paying in advance, like we do on Amazon?

Accounting questions are off-topic. But even for personal finance - consider why credit cards exist? Specifically for medium/large companies, I'm sure you've learned about accrual basis and what it means for recognition of income or expenses. Once you understand that you'll realize that the actual timing of the cash flow doesn't matter as much for income statements.

Where can I post an accounting question then?

The question might be asking one of two different questions. One is about accounting (accrual versus cash) and the other is about cash management (credit versus immediate payment).

The question is about cash management. Why big and medium companies don't pay immediately when they buy from a supplier but instead but afterwards

Unfortunately there's not a good forum here for either accounting or corporate finance. Questions here are typically limited to financial statement analysis as it would relate to individual investors.
